# Error with replaceText timestamp add a quota Nifi

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, timestamp, apache-nifi

I have a timestamp column in my flowfile written in this way 2008:05:17 17:23:01. I want to add a quota to this value so I can insert it in postgresql table. I used replace text like this :

search value :

```
 ((\d{4})([\-\/.])([0-3]?\d)\2([0-3]?\d)|([0-3]?\d)([\-\/.])([0-3]?\d)\6(\d{4}))(?:\s+([012]?\d)([:hap])([0-5]\d))([:hap])([0-5]\d)
```

replacement value :

```
 ' ((\d{4})([\-\/.])([0-3]?\d)\2([0-3]?\d)|([0-3]?\d)([\-\/.])([0-3]?\d)\6(\d{4}))(?:\s+([012]?\d)([:hap])([0-5]\d))([:hap])([0-5]\d) '
```

but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Could you confirm is your flowfile content timestamp and seperator is :(colon) always **2008:05:17 17:23:01** and you want to add quotes to timestamp like **'2008:05:17 17:23:01'** is this correct assumption ..? because i see your regex is not matching with the input content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you'd like to prepend and append single quotes to the whole group. You won't need a regular expression in the Replacement Value, rather you can refer to the group (I think it's the 0th group?), try this for the Replacement Value

```
'$0'
```

To insert to_timestamp, you should be able to use the following as a Replacement Value:

```
to_timestamp('$0', 'YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Having said that, what processor are you using to insert into PostgreSQL? I would think they would handle the quoting of a timestamp literal automatically (if they know the destination column is a timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather just use to_tmestamp instead:

```
s=# select to_timestamp('2008:05:17 17:23:0','YYYY:MM:DD HH24:MI:SS');
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2008-05-17 17:23:00+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: I use it in ReplaceText Processor like this ? with select to_timestamp?  i want to replace all the the timestamp to 'timestamp' i add '' so i can insert column in my table. I have a big file just i put one value to explain the problem